# Pyside QgraphicsScene can't capture mouse events

Tags: qt, pyqt, pyside, qt-signals, qt-events

I can't find the way to attach mouse events to scene. Without View all events are capcured, but when commented out, only mousePressEvent works. Please, help.

```
from PySide import QtGui, QtCore

class Window(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QtGui.QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        self.Scene()
        self.View()

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        if event.button() == QtCore.Qt.LeftButton:
            print "Pressed!!!"

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        print "moving....."

    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event):
        print "-------released"

    def Scene(self):
        self.s = QtGui.QGraphicsScene(self)

    def View(self):
        self.v = QtGui.QGraphicsView(self.s)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.v)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window()
    window.resize(300, 200)
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: I'm not sure what your goal is. If you put a `QGraphicsView` as central widget and click on it, then the view will get mouse events, not the parent (`QMainWindow`). That's normal.

Comment: But it's the opposite. View accepts ONLY mousePressEvent and other ignores (mouseMoveEvent, mouseReleaseEvent) like I wrote above.

Comment: No. Note that you're defining `mouse*Event` methods for the `QMainWindow`. If you see a `print` from those, that means the event takes place _in_ the `QMainWindow`, not the view. Why you see `pressed` with view depends on the default implementations of those events in `QGraphicsView`. I guess view ignores (and therefore passes to the parent) `mousePressEvent` if it can't do anything with them.

Comment: I'll write-up an answer to explain better.

Comment: Please. Thanks, I need events in view...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Qt, events are handled from child to parent. First the child gets the event. Then it decides whether or not it'll handle the event. If it doesn't want to act on it, it can `ignore` the event and the event will be passed to the parent.

In your setup, you have `QMainWindow` as the parent, and a `QGraphicsView` as its child. Every event on the `QGraphicsView` will be handled by the `QGraphicsView` first. If it doesn't want the event, it will `ignore` it and pass on to the `QMainWindow`.

To visualize it better, subclass `QGraphicsView` and override its `mouse*Event`s:

```
from PySide import QtGui, QtCore

class View(QtGui.QGraphicsView):
    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        print "QGraphicsView mousePress"

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        print "QGraphicsView mouseMove"

    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event):
        print "QGraphicsView mouseRelease"

class Window(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QtGui.QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        self.Scene()
        self.View()

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        print "QMainWindow mousePress"

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        print "QMainWindow mouseMove"

    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event):
        print "QMainWindow mouseRelease"

    def Scene(self):
        self.s = QtGui.QGraphicsScene(self)

    def View(self):
        self.v = View(self.s)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.v)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window()
    window.resize(300, 200)
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

And you'll see an output like:

```
QGraphicsView mousePress
QGraphicsView mouseMove
...
QGraphicsView mouseMove
QGraphicsView mouseRelease
```

As you can see, only the `view` gets to 'see' the events, because `view` doesn't choose to pass the events.

Alternatively, you can choose to ignore those events in the `QGraphicsView`. It's like saying 'I don't do anything with this, let someone else take care of it'. And the event will be passed to the parent for it to choose what to do:

```
class View(QtGui.QGraphicsView):
    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        print "QGraphicsView mousePress"
        # ignore the event to pass on the parent.
        event.ignore()

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        print "QGraphicsView mouseMove"
        event.ignore()

    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event):
        print "QGraphicsView mouseRelease"
        event.ignore()
```

And the output:

```
QGraphicsView mousePress
QMainWindow mousePress
QGraphicsView mouseMove
QMainWindow mouseMove
...
QGraphicsView mouseMove
QMainWindow mouseMove
QGraphicsView mouseRelease
QMainWindow mouseRelease
```

Now, you can see that `view` gets the event first. But since it `ignore`s the event, it's passed to the main window and only after that `QMainWindow` receives the signal.

*Long story short*, don't worry. Your `view` will receive events and act on them just fine.